# The problem with socket communication between client and server using node and python

Tags: python

I'm encountering a rather strange problem or maybe I don't understand where the mistake is.
My sockets server is hosted in node.js and everything works correctly.

The problem comes when I want to send something in the socket using the python instance

How do I go about this

```
def main() -> None:
    cache: Redis = Redis(config.REDIS_HOST, config.REDIS_PORT, config.REDIS_PASSWORD)

    ws = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ws.connect(("localhost", 3003))

    while True:
        try:
            ecommerce: Ecommerce = Ecommerce(cache=cache, ws=ws)
            ecommerce.recommendation()
        except EmptyRedisDataException as e:
            print(str(e))
            time.sleep(10)
        except Exception as e:
            write_log(f"{str(e)}", "error")
```

```
    def __init__(self, cache: Redis, ws) -> None:
        self.cache: Redis = cache
        self.ws = ws
```

And in the function where I need it, I call the "send" function from the socket to send data

```
        try:
            # based on the processed data, products are taken into the models
            products: object | None = self.product.get_products(data=data)

            print(f"Products founded for {data['session_id']}")

            # the status changes to true for processed actions
            self.action.update_processed(session_id=data['session_id'])
            # metadata + recommended products are updated for each session
            self.session.update_meta(data=data, products=products)

            self.ws.send("asdsadsadsadsadsa")
        except Exception as e:
            '''
            If we end up with no solutions because of the metadata 
            (or there are errors), they are updated as non-functional 
            and they are deleted from cache
            '''
            data['error'] = str(e)
            self.session.update_nonfunctional_meta(data=data)

            write_log(f'Find items error: {str(e)}', "error")
```

The problem is that nothing works, data is not sent.
Isn't that the right kind of approach?
It should be mentioned that I tested the server, and everything is ok there.